# Images in questions, stay or get deleted, after deleting the original source?

Tags: support, images

Let's say I post a question with an image/images on any SE network site. I uploaded that image on some website ( e.g. Dropbox ). Does the image stay on SE servers, if I delete it from the website where I uploaded it to ( e.g. Dropbox ), or will it get deleted from SE question too ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image only stays if you actually *upload* the image to the Stack Exchange Imgur service.

If you merely *link* to it in your post then no one can load it and it'll be gone.

In other words, an image linked like this:

```
![some image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f24uqb6e3mapg0l/some_image_link.png)
```

will not be uploaded to any Stack Exchange server.

Instead, use the image upload service, either from a local file or a URL (like your Dropbox link):

[image: image upload]

so that you end up uploading an image with a URL like:

```
![image upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFarg.png)
```

*These* images remain with your post, and are entirely independent of the original image URL on the web.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you added the image to your question. If you linked directly to your image on Dropbox, so if you have used this Markdown:

```
![Image][1]

  [1]:https://www.dropbox.com/path/image.png
```

Then the image will be gone after you deleted it on Dropbox, because you linked directly to it.

If you have used the "Add Image" widget from the toolbar (and chose "From the web"):

[image: Add Image]

Then you have *uploaded* your image to [i.stack.imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/), and then your image will still show up if you delete it from Dropbox.